# Get DAYNAME faiiled in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to get dayname from Monday to Sunday by using the laravel query builder.I'm gonna use to it to get the data for my chart.js bar chart
but when I try, there was an error of

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DAYNAME(created_at)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `watchlists` where `DAYNAME(created_at)` = Monday)
```

code in my controller

```
$monday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Monday')
      ->get()->count();

      $tuesday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Monday')
      ->get()->count();

      $wednesday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Wednesday')
      ->get()->count();

      $thursday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Thursday')
      ->get()->count();

      $firday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Friday')
      ->get()->count();

      $saturday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Saturday ')
      ->get()->count();

      $Sunday = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->where('DAYNAME(created_at)', 'Sunday')
      ->get()->count();

      $dayarray=[ $monday,$tuesday,$wednesday, $thursday,$firday, $saturday,  $Sunday];
```

What did I miss, or anything there is wrong
PS. My codes seem not that efficient, is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
$monday = DB::table('watchlists')
  ->whereDay('created_at','=', 'Monday')
  ->count();
```

Hello friend, If you are using the same version as I am using then it works well in this situation.

Just try to do short these all queries so you can get the result in one or two queries.
Thanks,
Gurpreet kait

Comment: Hello, I have tried this but it doesn't work . if not mistaken, the whereDay will return the value of 1-31 ... but what I need is Monday-Sunday. But anyway, thanks for the help